# How to use Jmeter and MQ Websphere To consume the message from the queue and Send that Request to an Api Endpoint

Tags: jmeter

All,I need to run a performance test on our application which has an endpoint that receives a message or claim, processes this claim, and sends us back the results.
I want to use Jmeter to connect to and Get the Message as part of my post request and send it to the endpoint.

I looked at some articles here: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-tutorial#Preparing

is it possible to have a sample on how i can get this message from the JMS Subscriber and consume it as part of my API request.

in this section not sure where and how i attach the message to the body or how this is done...
Step 5: Add an HTTP Request Sampler to Post Data

Add an HTTP Request Sampler:
Right-click on the Thread Group and choose Add -> Sampler -> HTTP Request.
Configure the HTTP Request Sampler with the HTTP endpoint URL where you want to post the data. Specify the HTTP method, path, and any necessary request parameters.
Step 6: Add Listeners

I am following this:

Install JMeter if you haven't already.
Make sure you have access to an IBM WebSphere MQ and the necessary permissions to interact with it.
Know the endpoint URL where you want to post the data.
Step 1: Set Up JMeter

Launch JMeter.
Create a new Test Plan: File -> New Test Plan.
Step 2: Add Thread Group

Right-click on the Test Plan and choose Add -> Threads (Users) -> Thread Group.
Configure the Thread Group according to your needs, setting the number of threads, ramp-up time, and loop count.
Step 3: Configure JMS Connection to IBM WebSphere MQ

Add a JMS Connection Factory Configuration:
Right-click on the Thread Group and choose Add -> Config Element -> JP@gc - JMS Configuration.
Configure the JMS Connection Factory with the necessary settings for your WebSphere MQ. Provide the JNDI properties and connection details.
Step 4: Add JMS Sampler to Receive Data

Add a JMS Subscriber Sampler:
Right-click on the Thread Group and choose Add -> Sampler -> JP@gc - JMS Subscriber.
Configure the JMS Subscriber Sampler with the necessary settings to pull data from WebSphere MQ.
Step 5: Add an HTTP Request Sampler to Post Data

Add an HTTP Request Sampler:
Right-click on the Thread Group and choose Add -> Sampler -> HTTP Request.
Configure the HTTP Request Sampler with the HTTP endpoint URL where you want to post the data. Specify the HTTP method, path, and any necessary request parameters.
Step 6: Add Listeners

Add Listeners to view the results of your test. Common listeners include "View Results Tree" and "Summary Report." Right-click on the Thread Group and choose Add -> Listener.
Step 7: Run the Test

Save your test plan: File -> Save Test Plan As...
Start the test: Run -> Start.
Make sure to customize the JMS Subscriber and HTTP Request Samplers with the specific details relevant to your WebSphere MQ and the HTTP endpoint you want to post the data to.

Please note that this is a basic outline, and the actual configuration will depend on the specifics of your WebSphere MQ setup and the endpoint you're working with. You may also need to install additional JMeter plugins if your use case requires them. Additionally, ensure that you have the necessary permissions and configurations to interact with your WebSphere MQ and post data to the endpoint.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> All,I need to run a performance test on our application which has an endpoint that receives a message or claim, processes this claim, and sends us back the results. I want to use Jmeter to connect to and Get the Message as part of my post request and send it to the endpoint.

If you want to measure the messare or claim processing speed by your application you need to simulate **sending** the message, not receiving it.

To wit you don't need to replicate the system under test functionality using JMeter, you need to generate hundreds/thousands of messages/claims and send them to your application to test its behaviour within the bounds of specific workload model.

So you will need only "Producer" part of the [IBM MQ Tutorial: Learn How to Testing With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-tutorial#Creating) article.

Additionally you can implement some polling logic to check if the processing is completed using [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) and use [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) to measure end-to-end processing time of the message or claim.